# Combine VBA Codes to Hide Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, vba, row, hide, worksheet

I'd like to combine the two Hide Row Codes, please help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheets("Re-Hire Questionnaire").Protect Password:="Testing2022!", UserInterFaceOnly:=True

If Range("B12").Value = False Then
Rows("9:11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Rows("9:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheets("Re-Hire Questionnaire").Protect Password:="Testing2022!", UserInterFaceOnly:=True

If Range("B19").Value = False Then
Rows("16:16").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Rows("16:16").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If
End Sub
```

Tried to place them underneath each other but didn't work. I'm a novice btw lol

Comment: Could you explain how this should work, e.g. *"if I select cell B12 the code... if the cell..."*?

Comment: Maybe try to set a range for the cell you want to be detected ... `set rg = range("b12,b19")`. Then give a condition to trigger the process if one of the cell in rg is selected ... `if not intersect(target,rg) is nothing then` ... `if target = range("b12") then` ... `if target.value = TRUE then Rows("9:11").EntireRow.Hidden = True else Rows("9:11").EntireRow.Hidden = false` ... `end if` ....  `if target = range("b19") then` ... `if target.value = TRUE then Rows("16:16").EntireRow.Hidden = True else Rows("16:16").EntireRow.Hidden = false` ... `end if`  ... `end if`. Not tested in my side.

Comment: Both are independent of each other.

If the value in B12 is false, then hide rows 9-11. If true, unhide rows 9-11.
If the value in B19 is false, then hide row 16. If true, unhide row 16

Comment: Karma, let me try it and see

Comment: What exactly is in those cells? The values `TRUE` or `FALSE` modified manually, or a formula? A dropdown would be great.

Comment: Its governed by Formulas, basically if a certain state is in two other cells, cell B12 and B19 will return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Selection Change: Hide Rows

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim TargetCells: TargetCells = Array("B12", "B19")
    Dim HideRows: HideRows = Array("9:11", "16:16")
    
    Dim tCell As Range, hRows As Range, n As Long, WasSelected As Boolean
    
    For n = LBound(TargetCells) To UBound(TargetCells)
        Set tCell = Me.Range(TargetCells(n))
        If Not Intersect(tCell, Target) Is Nothing Then
            Set hRows = Me.Rows(HideRows(n))
            hRows.EntireRow.Hidden = tCell.Value = False
            WasSelected = True
        End If
    Next n
    
    If WasSelected Then
        Me.Parent.Sheets("Re-Hire Questionnaire").Protect _
            Password:="Testing2022!", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: No luck, tried it and nothing happens. The True and False cells in B12 and B19 have a formula and that is how they are returning True or False